# Post have has duplicated properties

Tags: html, post

Problem is: I have form with radio buttons in it. One radio button checked as default. When I check another one and push apply button i have $_POST with duplicated properties but different values:
`country: 55`
`country: 72`
second one is previous checked value. Expected only one propertie.
I can't understand why this happens.

```
<div id="countries">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="country" type="radio" value="14" id="country_14" checked="checked"/>&nbsp;<label for="country_14">Austria</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="country" type="radio" value="117" id="country_117"/>&nbsp;<label for="country_117">Latvia</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="country" type="radio" value="21" id="country_21"/>&nbsp;<label for="country_21">Belgium</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="country" type="radio" value="123" id="country_123"/>&nbsp;<label for="country_123">Lithuania</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap>
            <input name="country" type="radio" value="33" id="country_33"/>&nbsp;<label for="country_33">Bulgaria</label>
        </td>
        <td nowrap>
            <input name="country" type="radio" value="124" id="country_124"/>&nbsp;<label for="country_124">Luxembourg</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML for us please?

Comment: Could you show us the HTML code of that form?

Answer (score 0):

probably the POST was an array POST, like:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
 <input value="val1" name="name[0]">
 <input value="val2" name="name[1]">
 <input type="sumbit" value="Submit">
</form>
```